# How to automatically generate jira defect for failed Jenkins Build?

Tags: java, jenkins, jira, defects

We want to create a defect in Jira automatically for a failed build in Jenkins. If you have done this successfully, can you share with it me?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the [JIRA plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira), and the "JIRA: Create issue" post-build action.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins Post Build Task allows you to run tasks in a job after failure. Rolling the server back sounds more like a task than a job, so that might suit.

Otherwise, there are a couple of plugins that allow for more complex pipelining features. The Pipeline Plugin seems to be the most popular at the moment.

Using [Jira Rest API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue) you can create an issue in JIRA.